# master detail xamarin forms using mvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I already start using mvvmcross and i want to learn how to use a master/detail navigation. I can't find MvxMasterDetailPage described in this solution.

I have spent two days trying to start a master/detail navigation and nothing. I wouold like to do it with Xamarin Forms; i don't want to create any other presenter class but use the MvxFormsDroidMasterDetailPagePresenter for android. I had tried create a MvxFormsDroidMasterDetailPagePresenter in setup and also use MvxMasterDetailViewModel and nothing work.

Can some one please explain me or guide me to others options. Thanks.

Comment: You can see my answer here [How to create a MasterDetailPage using MvvmCross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980485/how-to-create-a-masterdetailpage-using-mvvmcross/48981533#48981533) or you can check the [MvvmCross Playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/6.2.1/Projects/Playground) on the split pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MasterDetailPage using MvvmCross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980485/how-to-create-a-masterdetailpage-using-mvvmcross)